# What is the "blue spirit" (or "red spirit") in mercury-free thermometers?

Tags: equipment

I surmise it's some kind of alcohol, but is there a standard chemical used for these?

One of them just exploded in my students' lab! It was the kind with blue fluid in it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_thermometer

Comment: exploded, as in "ignited/fireball" or as in "overheated and glass broken due to pressure"?

Comment: @dlatikay the latter. Loud pop. No combustion that I know of

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the Wikipedia page on [Spirit Thermometers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_thermometer):

> The liquid used can be pure ethanol, toluene, kerosene or isoamyl acetate, depending on manufacturer and working temperature range. Since these are transparent, the liquid is made more visible by the addition of a red or blue dye.

1,4-bis(butylamino)anthraquinone - commonly known as "Oil Blue 35" - may possibly be used as the blue dye.

Answer (score 13):

Another organic solvent used may be **pentane**. Perhaps the common ones contain toluene dyed with a **red aniline dye** .

Other spirit filled thermometers variants include:

- Blue fill contains **isoamyl benzoate**;
- Red fill may contain **kerosene** or **pentane** with aniline dye

---

**Aniline red**

[image]
<sub>*[Credits](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bleu_d%27aniline_red.PNG)*</sub>

**Acknowledgements**

- Spirit-Filled Glass Thermometers: [Document](http://lab.ro/document/document321.pdf)